# What is the best way to add missing packages?

Tags: packages, vim, cite-package

So far I worked with Texmaker on Windows, and it worked perfectly.
Recently I started to write my .tex files with vim on Ubuntu.
But when I try to compile these it tells me `File 'cite.sty' not found.` How should I install the needed packages?

I am quite new to this topic, I started using vim with the plugin LaTeX-Box, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if Vim has en embeded solution for that, but as you are on Linux, I think you are using TexLive, so you have two ways to install new packages :

1. If the package is part of TexLive, you may use `sudo tlmgr install package_name`.
2. If the package is only located on CTAN, you will have to move the `.sty` file of the package to the appropriate location. This point has already been detailed in another post ([Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te)).

I hope it may be useful.

**EDIT**

If an error stating `running on Debian, switching to user mode!` happened, initialize `tlmgr` with `tlmgr init-usertree`.

Comment: Trying to use your first advice gives me this error:
`(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
cannot setup TLPDB in /home/jonas/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5336.`

Comment: That's a common problem. This error may have been raised because you don't initialize `tlmgr`. To do so, type `tlmgr init-usertree` (normally, as usual user would be enough).

Comment: thanks, this and installing `xzdec` solved the problem.